# How to retrieve the attributes of an elements parent container

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, attributes

I have multiple cardviews within a linear layout, within each card there are two checkboxes. How do I get the text attribute of the container (Cardview) that my checkbox sits in?

I've scoured the Xamarin.Android documentation looking to see if there's a way to access the parent or container of an element. I saw that Xamarin.Forms has a Element class that can be used to access the parent of an element.

I have tried capturing the text from the Cardview and putting it into a string, this won't work as the text can vary dependent on cardview from which the checkbox is being checked.

```
//Here are my initialisers
btnOrder = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnOrder);
pancakeTypeSpnr = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.pancaketypespnr);
pancakeStyleSpnr = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.pancakestylespnr);
pancakeQuantitySpnr = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.pancakequantityspnr);

cardSugar = FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cardSugar);
cardSugar.Click += CardSugar_Click;

cardLemonJuice = FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cardLemonJuice);
cardLemonJuice.Click += CardLemonJuice_Click;

cardGoldenSyrup = FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cardGoldenSyrup);
cardGoldenSyrup.Click += CardGoldenSyrup_Click;

cardMarmite = FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cardMarmite);
cardMarmite.Click += CardMarmite_Click;

cardStrawberries = FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cardStrawberries);
cardStrawberries.Click += CardStrawberries_Click;

cardChocolateSpread = FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cardChocolateSpread);
cardChocolateSpread.Click += CardChocolateSpread_Click;

cardBlueberries = FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.cardBlueberries);
cardBlueberries.Click += CardBlueberries_Click;

//Topping checkbox reference
checkToppingSugar = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingSugar);
checkToppingLemonJuice = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingLemonJuice);
checkToppingGoldenSyrup = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingGoldenSyrup);
checkToppingMarmite = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingMarmite);
checkToppingStrawberries = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingStrawberries);
checkToppingChocolateSpread = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingChocolateSpread);
checkToppingBlueberries = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingBlueberries);

//Filling checkbox reference
checkFillingSugar = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkFillingSugar);
checkFillingLemonJuice = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkFillingLemonJuice);
checkFillingGoldenSyrup = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkFillingGoldenSyrup);
checkFillingMarmite = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkFillingMarmite);
checkFillingStrawberries = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkFillingStrawberries);
checkFillingChocolateSpread = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkFillingChocolateSpread);
checkFillingBlueberries = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkFillingBlueberries);

The following is my Order button code

 //Order button... Completes initial check to see if compulsary boxes have been checked, then compiles order
private void BtnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (pancakeTypeSpnr.SelectedItemPosition == 0)
{
   Toast.MakeText(this, "You must select a pancake type!", 
   ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
   else if (pancakeStyleSpnr.SelectedItemPosition == 0)
{
   Toast.MakeText(this, "You must select a pancake style!", 
   ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
   else if (pancakeQuantitySpnr.SelectedItemPosition == 0)
{
   Toast.MakeText(this, "You must order at least one pancake", 
   ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
   else
{

/*This section takes all the checkboxes and checks them to see if they are checked. If they are, they are put into an array of checked boxes*/

CheckBox[] checkBoxesToppings = { checkToppingSugar, checkToppingLemonJuice, checkToppingGoldenSyrup, checkToppingMarmite, checkToppingStrawberries, checkToppingChocolateSpread, checkToppingBlueberries };
toppingsReturned = CheckDetails(checkBoxesToppings);
string toppings = "";
foreach (CheckBox toppingbox in toppingsReturned)
   {
    toppings = toppings + toppingbox.Tag.ToString() + "\n";
   }

CheckBox[] checkBoxesFillings = { checkFillingSugar, checkFillingLemonJuice, checkFillingGoldenSyrup, checkFillingMarmite, checkFillingStrawberries, checkFillingChocolateSpread, checkFillingBlueberries };
fillingsReturned = CheckDetails(checkBoxesFillings);
string fillings = "";
foreach (CheckBox fillingbox in fillingsReturned)
   {
    fillings = fillings + fillingbox.Text.ToString() + "\n";
   }

//This toast is for testing purposes only
string order = "The following has been added to your order:\n" +
pancakeQuantitySpnr.SelectedItem + "\n" +
"Pancake type: " + pancakeTypeSpnr.SelectedItem + "\n" +
"Pancake style: " + pancakeStyleSpnr.SelectedItem + "\n" +
"Fillings: " + "\n" + fillings +
"Toppings: " + "\n" + toppings;
Toast.MakeText(this, order, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
}

private CheckBox[] CheckDetails(CheckBox[] details)
{
var checkedCheckboxes = new List<CheckBox>();
foreach (CheckBox cb in details)
{
if (cb.Checked == true)
{
checkedCheckboxes.Add(cb);
}
else continue;
}
CheckBox[] ticked = checkedCheckboxes.ToArray();
return ticked;
}
```

When the order button is clicked, I want the BtnOrder_Click method code to be able to tell which card (i.e Sugar, Chocolate Spread) the topping/filling checkbox was clicked from.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried capturing the text from the Cardview and putting it into a string, this won't work as the text can vary dependent on cardview from which the checkbox is being checked.

I could get the text of cardview like below. It works well when the checkbox is selected and the text changed.

1.Get the text according to the id of your TextViews

```
var str = textView.Text;
```

The code you provided does not show how to change the text, I use the code below to test. The textview is in cardSugar Cardview.

```
  var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);

        var checkToppingSugar = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkToppingSugar);
        checkToppingSugar.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (checkToppingSugar.Checked)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Selected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                textView.Text = "textView Topping Selected";
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Not selected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                textView.Text = "textView Topping Not selected";
            }

        };
```

2.Get text via foreach all the element in linearlayout. It needs to match the layout you defined. **You could refer to the layout in my project**. I output the results on output window.

```
  var linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearlayout_view);
            for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                View child = linearLayout.GetChildAt(i);
                if (child.GetType() == typeof(CardView))
                {
                    var viewGroup = ((ViewGroup)child).GetChildAt(0);

                    for (int j = 0; j < ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).ChildCount; j++)
                    {
                        var viewGroup2 = ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).GetChildAt(j);
                        if (viewGroup2.GetType() == typeof(TextView))
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(viewGroup2.GetType().ToString() + ": " + ((TextView)viewGroup2).Text);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

> When the order button is clicked, I want the BtnOrder_Click method code to be able to tell which card (i.e Sugar, Chocolate Spread) the topping/filling checkbox was clicked from.

I suggest you to put the checkbox inside Cardview so that we could connect both of them. You could get the cardview when you check the checkbox like below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                View child = linearLayout.GetChildAt(i);
                if (child.GetType() == typeof(CardView))
                {
                    var viewGroup = ((ViewGroup)child).GetChildAt(0);

                    for (int j = 0; j < ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).ChildCount; j++)
                    {
                        var viewGroup2 = ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).GetChildAt(j);
                        if (viewGroup2.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                        {
                            if (((CheckBox)viewGroup2).Checked)
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((CardView)child));
                            }                               
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Result: The last time, cardsuger output twice because I check both checkboxes(Topping and Filling) of cardsuger.
[image]

You could download from Cardview/AndroidDemo folder of GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Comment: Hi Wendy, thank you for your answer. I am going to try this now and get back to you.